# Активные ссылки в навигации

Tags: javascript, html, scss

[image]
не могу понять как сделать что бы желтый прямоугольник **плавно** переезжал к активному пункту меню при наведении(mouseenter), нужно реализовать на js.
пробовал добавлять активный класс каждой ссылке при **mouseenter**,
но тогда желтый прямоугльник просто появляется возле активной ссылки что не совсем решение(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оранжевому блоку дать

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
transition: left 0.3s;
```

При наведении - переключать ему left на 0 / 25 / 50 / 75% (в зависимости от кол-ва и позиционирования блоков), пусть CSS сам анимирует перемещение.

```js
let pointer = document.querySelector(".pointer");

let a = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", highlight);
}

function highlight(e) {
  let index = [].indexOf.call(a, this);
  // this — элемент, на который наведена мышка.
  // Находит его номер среди всех ссылок `a`
  
  pointer.style.left = index * 100 / a.length + "%";
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

nav .pointer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 12.5%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-right: none;
  
  transition: left 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

nav a {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Impact;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #123;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">111</a>
  <a href="#">222</a>
  <a href="#">333</a>
  <a href="#">444</a>
  
  <div class="pointer"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Сдалал тоже самое но для аккрдеона. 
Все работает отличн, но при открытии аккордеона ранжевый блок смещается не правильно, может как то отслеживать высоту бловок по которым он перемещается?

Comment: @АртурКузьмич Нельзя точно сказать без разметки. А если добавить еще `top: 0;` ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/artur-alexandrowich/pen/poEBLzy
вот кодпен, когда открываю акоордеон желтый блк сьезжает не правильно

Comment: @АртурКузьмич Будет работать, если заменить селектор `".accordion_wrapper .accordion_item"` → `".accordion_wrapper .accordion_item-heading"` и позиционирование процентами заменить на `pointer.style.top = a[index].offsetTop - a[index].clientHeight / 2 + 'px';` пиксельную. Тогда придется пересчитывать на window.onresize, если это важно.

Comment: Поменял, все работает очень хорошо. 
Я не совсем понимаю что ты имеешь в виду под **пересчитывать на ресайзе? **
Знаю как делается, но как это влиять будет на желтый блок?

Comment: @АртурКузьмич Ну позиционирование устанавливается строго в пикселях, если поменяют размер окна, в теории может съехать (если например текст станет длиннее из-за нехватки ширины).

Comment: понял, спасибо громное, с ресайзом решу :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно также и на CSS без использования JavaScript. Анимация при наведении. Пример:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 2px solid orange;
}

nav a {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Impact;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #123;
}

nav .pointer {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14.5%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 12.5%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-right: none;
  transition: left 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav a:nth-child(1):hover~.pointer {
  left: 0%;
}

nav a:nth-child(2):hover~.pointer {
  left: 25%;
}

nav a:nth-child(3):hover~.pointer {
  left: 50%;
}

nav a:nth-child(4):hover~.pointer {
  left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">111</a>
  <a href="#">222</a>
  <a href="#">333</a>
  <a href="#">444</a>
  <div class="pointer"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: хорошее решение но на js решение #OPIMUS PRIME мне подходит больше, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для желтого элемента

```
position:absolute
```

Дальше при наведении мыши на пункт меню считываете его координаты слева, после перемещаете желтый элемент на это значение.